# how can i find as well as update many documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update the results of find query on certain conditions.now what i was thinking it that will mongodb will search whole collection for find and update or use pointer from the previous find query.I just wanted to optimism my queries that's why i was thinking about it.so is there anyway to achieve this?

update:I also want the documents.

ex-collection.find({conditions}).foreach({some condition based on which update will be called})

now what i want is that update query which will be called from foreach function uses pointer from previous find query rather than searching through the collection again.

my point is when we first use find query we search the collection and a cursor is returned which is a pointer to collection in memory.now that we have that pointer why can't we use that to update the document rather than again searching the collection and then updating it.

Comment: Does the [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#definition) command not already do what you need to do?  It accepts a query and instructions on how you want the resultant documents updated.  Please clarify how this does not do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code you can use:

```
collection.find({conditions}).foreach((doc) => {
       if (some_conditions) {
          return collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {updated_fields});
       }   
})
```

but as mentioned in the comments i'm not sure exactly what conditions need to be met but you probably can just use the `update` method to save time.

Comment: i think mongo db just search the collection(even though indexes will be used) for collection.findOneAndUpdate. so how it is optimised as it is not using any pointer.              
    my point is when we first use find query we search the collection and a cursor is returned which is a pointer to collection in memory.now that we have that pointer why can't we use that to update the document rather than again searching the collection and then updating it.